# Custom Firefox Scrollbar - Border Radius

Tags: html, css, angular, firefox, scrollbar

I am trying to modify the default CSS of browser scrollbar and its working fine for Chrome and Edge but not in Firefox. Is there any way i can modify the firefox browser scrollbar and make it in sync with Chrome and Edge. Currently i am not able to provide border radius to Scrollbar in Firefox.

Code that i have used :

```
/* Custom Scroll Bar */

/* Works on Firefox */
* {
  scrollbar-width: thin !important;
  scrollbar-color: #65676a #1e1f22 !important;
}

/* Works on Chrome, Edge, and Safari */
*::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 1.2rem !important;
  height: 1.2rem !important;
}

*::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #1e1f22 !important;
}

*::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: #65676a !important;
  border-radius: 2rem !important;
  border: 0.3rem solid #1e1f22 !important;
}

*::-webkit-scrollbar-corner {
  background: #1e1f22 !important;
}
```

Also, i am using Angular Framework, if there is any angular library to modify scrollbar then please share. I have tried ngx-scrollbar but having some build issue in that.

[image]

[image]

Comment: photos too big. use a collapsible section for photos - <details><summary></summary></details>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't achieve that in Firefox using css.

It will ignore the `::-webkit` properties since it doesn't use webkit. Chromium-based browsers accept it, since they use Blink engine which is based on the webkit.

Gecko (which is the rendering engine for Firefox) only accepts two standard properties that you have already listed: `scrollbar-width` and `scrollbar-color`.

Your best bet (if this is an absolute requirement) is to use a non-native scrollbar replacement. Personally I think those introduce more issues than they offer gain, but pick your poison. Example could be [perfect scrollbar](https://github.com/mdbootstrap/perfect-scrollbar), but I'm sure there's more out there if you search.